# Kafka jdbc connect sink: Is it possible to use pk.fields for fields in value and key?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

The issue i'm having is that when jdbc sink connector consumes kafka message, the key variables when writing to db is null.

However, when i consume directly through the kafka-avro-consumer - I can see the key and value variables with it's values because I use this config:     --property print.key=true.

ASK: is there away to make sure that jdbc connector is processing the message key variable values?

console kafka-avro config

```
/opt/confluent-5.4.1/bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer \
    --bootstrap-server "localhost:9092" \
    --topic equipmentidentifier.persist \
    --property parse.key=true \
    --property key.separator=~ \
    --property print.key=true \
    --property schema.registry.url="http://localhost:8081" \
    --property key.schema=[$KEY_SCHEMA] \
    --property value.schema=[$IDENTIFIER_SCHEMA,$VALUE_SCHEMA]
```

error:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.RetriableException: java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO "assignment_table" ("created_date","custome
r","id_type","id_value") VALUES('1970-01-01 03:25:44.567+00'::timestamp,123,'BILL_OF_LADING','BOL-123') was aborted: ERROR: null value in column "equipment_ide
ntifier_type" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, null, null, null, 1970-01-01 03:25:44.567, 123, id, 56).  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "equipment_identifier_type" violates not-null constraint
```

Sink config:

```
task.max=1
topic=assignment
connect.class=io.confluet.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector

connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
connection.user=test
connection.password=test

table.name.format=assignment_table
auto.create=false
insert.mode=insert
pk.fields=customer,equip_Type,equip_Value,id_Type,id_Value,cpId

transforms=flatten

transforms.flattenKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten$Key
transforms.flattenKey.delimiter=_

transforms.flattenKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten$Value
transforms.flattenKey.delimiter=_
```

Kafka key:

```
{
  "assignmentKey": {
    "cpId": {
      "long": 1001
    },
    "equip": {
      "Identifier": {
        "type": "eq",
        "value": "eq_45"
      }
    },
    "vendorId": {
      "string": "vendor"
    }
  }
}
```

Kafka value:

```
{
  "assigmentValue": {
    "id": {
      "Identifier": {
        "type": "id",
        "value": "56"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": {
      "long": 1234456756
    },
    "customer": {
      "long": 123
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the connector to use fields from the key, because by default it won't.

```
pk.mode=record_key
```

*However* you need to use fields from *either* the Key *or* the Value, not both as you have in your config currently:

```
pk.fields=customer,equip_Type,equip_Value,id_Type,id_Value,cpId
```

If you set `pk.mode=record_key` then `pk.fields` will refer to the fields in the message key.

Ref: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/sink_config_options.html#sink-pk-config-options

See also https://rmoff.dev/kafka-jdbc-video

Comment: Thank for the clarification. This was extremely helpful - Best Issa